# is the induced map of an embedding an Iso on Ext-groups?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

I am sorry, but I am quite new to Ext groups of sheaves. However, I have a closed embedding of projective $\mathbb{C}$-schemes $\iota : X \hookrightarrow Y$ and was wondering if
$$\iota_*:\mathrm{Ext}^*_X(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}) \to \mathrm{Ext}^*_Y (\iota_*\mathcal{F},\iota_*\mathcal{G})$$ was an iso, respectively if there are certain properties of that map that I may exploit to control said map.

Comment: A simple counterexample is given by the inclusion $pt \hookrightarrow \mathbb P^1$ (we might just as well replace $\mathbb P^1$ with $\mathbb A^1$). Obviously the ext groups are trivial on a point, but the skyscraper sheaf does have higher self-exts, as computed by the Koszul complex. I expect that your map is almost never an isomorphism for this reason.

Comment: thanks a lot! then I will give up that hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is an adjunction isomorphism
$$
Ext^\bullet(i_*F,i_*G) \cong Ext^\bullet(Li^*(i_*F),G),
$$
where $Li^*$ is the derived pullback functor. Furthermore, if $X$ in $Y$ is a locally complete intersection, then
$$
L_pi^*(i_*F) \cong F \otimes \Lambda^pN^\vee_{X/Y}.
$$
These two observations combine into a spectral sequence
$$
E_2^{p,q} = Ext^q(F \otimes \Lambda^pN^\vee_{X/Y}, G),
$$
whose first row is formed by $Ext^\bullet(F,G)$ and that converges to $Ext^n(i_*F,i_*G)$.

Comment: thanks a lot! that helps quite a bit! In particular since I am working with derived categories, and need that ext for controlling them.